# Findbugs for Ant XML files

Tags: xml, ant, metrics, findbugs, checkstyle

We have a pretty big project and ant xmls grow fast as hell. We already have different static code analysis tools integrated, and I am looking for something like checkstyle+findbugs, but for ANT XMLs, to validate the correctness of the file, maybe to find unused properties, etc.

Do anybody know anything like this?

Comment: *"and ant xmls grow fast as hell"* ... I wouldn't need a static code analysis tool for that. SCNR ;-)

Comment: I suggest using Sonar to run your source code analysis. The Sonar ANT task will run checkstyle, PMD and Findbugs for you automatically. It's worth taking some time to learn how it works.

Comment: Actually I am looking for this too FOR sonar, because sonar is just a storage for metrics. Almost all codebase is covered with some metrics already, pmd, jmi, findbugs, and only ANT XML files are not.

Answer (score 0):

Both IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse provide excellent Ant support.

## [IntelliJ Ant Support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/ant.html)

> ### Coding Assistance
>
> When editing Ant build files in IntelliJ IDEA, you can enjoy the following advanced editing features:
>
> - Syntax highlighting.
> - Code completion. In particular, code completion is provided for the properties of the File type.
> - Navigating to declaration <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
> - Using Structure view.
> - Rename refactoring.
> - Code folding.
> - Reformatting.
> - **Validation.**
> - Viewing parameter information <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
> - Viewing quick info **GuiDesigner.QuickJavadoc.** In particular, if classpath is defined as a path-like structures, the View Quick Info command for the fileset or dirset directives displays the actual files and directories on the disk, to which these directives are resolved.
>
> ### Path-Like Structures
>
> IntelliJ IDEA enables using path-like structures in the task definitions. If a classpath is defined as a path-like structure, the paths in the fileset and dirset directives are resolved into the actual files and directories on the disk. All JARs, required for performing the task, should be placed to the same place that contains the JAR with task definitions.

## [Eclipse Ant Editor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-anteditor.htm)

> - Syntax highlighting
> - Content/code assist (including Ant specific templates)
> - Annotations

Comment: but it is expected to be as a part of NightlyBuild not a feature for an IDE, so I think this should be some small tool such as findbugs.. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Ant task [XMLValidate](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlvalidate.html)?

Comment: thats not exactly what is required.. I need to validate it agains ANT API more than agains XML schema...